# How to write different classes into one excel sheet in R

Tags: r, excel

I have a set of data containing both characters and numerics in R. I know that I cannot save them in a data frame since the columns have to have all the same type. Therefore I saved them in a list.

Is there a way to save this list into an excel sheet so that the numerics are saved as numbers and the characters as characters?

I have been using XLConnect sa far and it works for a data frame, where you have columns with either all numerics or all characters

Thanks in advance

Example:

I have several measurements of different quantities (let's call them a and b).

These measurements can either be a number (numeric) or "n.d." (character). For example 3 measurements:
    First:   a = 5, b ="n.d."
    Second:  a = 3, b = 4
    Third:   a = "n.d.", b = "n.d."

EDIT:

The solution given by Roland works great:

Encode the missing values as `NA` in the data frame to have the columns all as numerics.
Then use
`setMissingValue(wb, value = "n.d.")`
to set the missing cells to "n.d." in the Excel sheet

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Comment: A dataframe is just a special kind of list, so you should be able to have both character and numeric variables in the same data frame (as long as they are in different columns).  Could you give an example of what format your data are in?

Comment: This is exactly my problem! My data consists of several measurements of certain quantities which can either give a number or "n.d.". Therefore I have in the same column most of the times both numbers and characters.

Comment: Instead of `"n.d."` you should encode your missing values as `NA`, which can be of type numeric in R.

Comment: @Roland This solution of course also came to mind to me. I however would prefer a way of doing it directly from R in the final format and not have to search and replace the corresponding cells in Excel afterwards

Comment: I don't use XLConnect, but it should be possible to specify an `na` string like in `write.csv`. Using anything different than `NA` for missing values in R is just asking for trouble.

Comment: This works great! I didn't know about the MissingValue-string.

So the magic command in XLConnect is `setMissingValue(wb, value = "n.d.")`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnDoe Can you please turn your edit to the question into an actual answer and accept it? You'll get some internet points for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by Roland works great:

Encode the missing values as `NA` in the data frame to have the columns all as numerics.
Then use
`setMissingValue(wb, value = "n.d.")`
to set the missing cells to "n.d." in the Excel sheet

Thanks a lot for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

Given the example:

`df=data.frame(a=c(5,'n.d.','n.d.'),b=c('n.d.',4,'n.d.'))`,

you can use

`write.csv(df,file='data.csv')`

Then you can import the CSV file into Excel manually.

Comment: Would this suffice or do you want to do it all automated through R?

Comment: I would of course prefer everything to be automated through R, but is there is no way of doing it I can take the extra step through the csv.
However I am not sure this solves my original problem, because, as far as I understand the data frame, a and b still have to be of the same type which would be character as the smallest common denominator...

Comment: Also, I think the XLConnect package works well saving data frames in Excel sheets directly. So I don't think the extra step through the csv is necessary